# What is the purpose of "explicit" for a default constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor, explicit, explicit-constructor

I recently noticed a class in C++0x that calls for an explicit default constructor.  However, I'm failing to come up with a scenario in which a default constructor can be called implicitly.  It seems like a rather pointless specifier.  I thought maybe it would disallow `Class c;` in favor of `Class c = Class();` but that does not appear to be the case.

Some relevant quotes from the C++11 FCD, since it is easier for me to navigate [similar text exists in C++03, if not in the same places]

> 12.3.1.3 [class.conv.ctor]
>
> A default constructor may be an explicit constructor; such a constructor will be used to perform default-initialization or value initialization (8.5).

It goes on to provide an example of an explicit default constructor, but it simply mimics the example I provided above.

> 8.5.6 [decl.init]
>
> To default-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
>
> 8.5.7 [decl.init]
>
> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with a user-provided constructor (12.1), then the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);

In both cases, the standard calls for the default constructor to be called.  But that is what would happen if the default constructor were non-explicit.  For completeness sake:

> 8.5.11 [decl.init]
>
> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized;

From what I can tell, this just leaves conversion from no data.  Which doesn't make sense.  The best I can come up with would be the following:

```
void function(Class c);
int main() {
  function(); //implicitly convert from no parameter to a single parameter
}
```

But obviously that isn't the way C++ handles default arguments.  What else is there that would make `explicit Class();` behave differently from `Class();`?

The specific example that generated this question was `std::function` [20.8.14.2 func.wrap.func].  It requires several converting constructors, none of which are marked explicit, but the default constructor is.

Comment: As soon as I hit post, I think I came up with an explanation.  But I'll wait for confirmation of my suspicions, since this seems like a useful question anyhow.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This declares an explicit default constructor:

```
struct A {
  explicit A(int a1 = 0);
};

A a = 0; /* not allowed */
A b; /* allowed */
A c(0); /* allowed */
```

In case there is no parameter, like in the following example, the `explicit` is redundant.

```
struct A {
  /* explicit is redundant. */
  explicit A();
};
```

In some C++0x draft (I believe it was n3035), it made a difference in the following way:

```
A a = {}; /* error! */
A b{}; /* alright */

void function(A a);
void f() { function({}); /* error! */ }
```

But in the FCD, they [changed this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#990) (though, I suspect that they didn't have this particular reason in mind) in that all three cases *value-initialize* the respective object. Value-initialization doesn't do the overload-resolution dance and thus won't fail on explicit constructors.

Comment: Okay.  Then the explicit constructor for `std::function` is simply a hold over from that version of the draft?  It was this explanation that I finally figured out after writing the question, but neither the provided example nor `std::function()` took an optional parameter, so I wasn't entirely convinced.

Comment: This seems to have changed a bit, see [CWG 1518](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1518). Recent versions of g++ and clang++ reject `function({})` for non-defaulted explicit default constructors, even in C++11 mode.

Comment: @VilleVoutilainen that seems to be another wart of the core language. Why do we not consider `explicit` default constructors for default initialization triggered by `= {}` when value initializing, but *do* consider `explicit` constructors when looking for constructors triggered by `= { foo }` when *not* value initializing? My first reaction to that LWG issue resolution was "oh no that will not work, because list-initialization considers `explicit` constructors, and only when they are chosen the program is ill-formed.". Wrong litb, C++ has another warty special case here for extra confusion :/

Comment: @VilleVoutilainen in http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25673a34a62d668e , GCC says that the call is ambiguous. Yet if you remove the `void f(B)` overload ( http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ee73c36f3d346e0 ), it complains about the use of explicit constructors. It looks like GCC needs some polishing aswell here (GCC6.3) to implement this IMO wart aswell.

Comment: @VilleVoutilainen actually, I think my initial reaction seems to be correct and GCC's behavior is correct aswell, but the LWG resolution is incorrect.  Because the language specifies that during overload resolution, the `{} -> A` conversion sequence has no special case for default initialization, but uses the general "consider explicit ctors, and reject if an explicit one is chosen": Quote: *"If the initializer list has no elements and T has a default constructor, the first phase is omitted. In copy-list-initialization, if an explicit constructor is chosen, the initialization is ill-formed."*

Comment: GCC's behavior is just incorrect (all with regard to the draft that I looked at, and assuming I haven't missed something) with regard to this testcase: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/449ad727f2ca3575 which I think should take the second constructor. It just doesn't work this way when building up a conversion sequence for `{} -> A`. I hope that this will be fixed for C++17, so that overload resolution (in clauses 13.3.3.1.5) correctly will model the semantics of the parameter initialization.

Comment: We had a similar issue back in the days when preparing C++11: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1229 . The issue then was fixed by adding the "If the initializer list has no elements and T has a default constructor, the first phase is omitted. " (therefore ignoring the two initializer list constructors, and then using the default constructors).

Comment: Recent versions of g++ and clang also reject `A a = {};`, and `struct C { A a; };` with a subsequent `C c{};`

Comment: @m.m yes they didn't want to change this and decided they want to require nonexplicit ctors.

Answer (score 8):

<sub>*Unless explicitly stated otherwise, all standard references below refers to [N4659: March 2017 post-Kona working draft/C++17 DIS](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/).*</sub>

---

*(This answer focus specifically on explicit default constructors which have no parameters)*

---

#### Case #1 [*C++11 through C++20*]: Empty `{}` copy-list-initialization for non-aggregates prohibits use of explicit default constructors

As governed by [[over.match.list]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.list#1) [**emphasis** mine]:

> When objects of non-aggregate class type `T` are list-initialized such
> that [dcl.init.list] specifies that overload resolution is performed
> according to the rules in this section, overload resolution selects
> the constructor in two phases:
>
> - *(1.1)* Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors ([dcl.init.list]) of the class `T` and the argument list
>   consists of the initializer list as a single argument.
> - *(1.2)* If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all
>   the constructors of the class `T` and the argument list consists of
>   the elements of the initializer list.
>
> If the initializer list has no elements and `T` has a default
> constructor, the first phase is omitted. **In
> copy-list-initialization, if an `explicit` constructor is chosen, the
> initialization is ill-formed.** [ *Note:* This differs from other
> situations ([over.match.ctor], [over.match.copy]), where only
> converting constructors are considered for copy-initialization. This
> restriction only applies if this initialization is part of the final
> result of overload resolution.  — *end note* ]

*copy-list-initialization* with an empty *braced-init-list* `{}` for non-aggregates prohibits use of explicit default constructors; e.g.:

```
struct Foo {
    virtual void notAnAggregate() const {};
    explicit Foo() {}
};

void foo(Foo) {}

int main() {
    Foo f1{};    // OK: direct-list-initialization

    // Error: converting to 'Foo' from initializer
    // list would use explicit constructor 'Foo::Foo()'
    Foo f2 = {};
    foo({});
}
```

Albeit the standard quote above refers to C++17, this likewise applies for C++11, C++14 and C++20.

---

#### Case #2 [*C++17 only*]: A class type with a user-declared constructor that is marked as `explicit` is not an aggregate

[[dcl.init.aggr]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.aggr#1) added was updated some between C++14 and C++17, mainly by allowing an aggregate to derive publicly from a base class, with some restrictions, but also prohibiting `explicit` constructors for aggregates [**emphasis** mine]:

> An *aggregate* is an array or a class with
>
> - (1.1) **no user-provided, `explicit`**, or inherited *constructors* ([class.ctor]),
> - (1.2) no private or protected non-static data members (Clause [class.access]),
> - (1.3) no virtual functions, and
> - (1.4) no virtual, private, or protected base classes ([class.mi]).

As of [P1008R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1008r1.pdf) (*Prohibit aggregates with user-declared constructors*), which has been implemented for C++20, we may no longer ever declare constructors for aggregates. In C++17 alone, however, we had the peculiar rule that whether a user-declared (but not user-provided) constructor was marked explicit decided whether the class type was an aggregate or not. E.g. the class types

```
struct Foo {
    Foo() = default;
};

struct Bar {
    explicit Bar() = default;
};
```

were aggregates/not aggregates in C++11 through C++20 as follows:

- C++11: `Foo` & `Bar` are both aggregates
- C++14: `Foo` & `Bar` are both aggregates
- C++17: Only `Foo` is an aggregate (`Bar` has an `explicit` constructor)
- C++20: None of `Foo` or `Bar` are aggregates (both has user-declared constructors)