# what c++ inline explicit constructor is good for?

Tags: c++, inline

i see sometimes this constructor writing with inline explicit.
for example:

```
protected : 
    inline explicit Singleton() { 

        CCASSERT(Singleton::instance_ == 0, "error Singleton::instance_ == 0."); 
        Singleton::instance_ = static_cast<T*>(this); 
    }
    inline ~Singleton() { 
        Singleton::instance_ = 0; 
    }
```

for what inline explicit is good for ?

Comment: `inline` and `explicit` are two different keywords. So I guess you're asking what `explicit` means, which has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean).

Comment: Are you asking about the combination between `inline` and `explicit`? Because that doesn't add anything to the respective behaviors of these two modifiers.

Comment: @Zeta But what sense makes `explicit` without any constructor parameter??

Comment: explicit on a no-arg constructor makes sense in c++11 to circumvent brace initialisation.

Comment: btw, as far as i know, if you put the body of the function in the { } right in the class, the function is inlined by default

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, see [Purpose of Explicit Default Constructors](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2836939/464709).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi THX, good to know. The answer there says, `explicit` is redundant for the OP's case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`inline` is necessary if you define a function in a header, but not in a class definition. It allows the function to be defined in multiple translation units (i.e. when including the header from multiple source files). The purpose is to allow the compiler to inline calls to the function - many compilers require the definition to be available within the translation unit in order to do that.

In this case it's pointless: functions defined within a class definition are implicitly inline.

`explicit` means that the constructor can't be used for implicit type conversions. Historically, it only made sense for single-argument constructors; but I think these days it can also be used to prevent brace-initialisation.

In this case, it's also pointless: default constructors aren't used for implicit conversions.

> for what inline explicit is good for ?

Here, they both give useful code smells - the author values verbiage and excessive structure over clarity. This is further evidenced by the use of the Singleton anti-pattern - tread carefully in this code.

Comment: +1: But I would state that within a class definition, `inline` is implicit for all functions defined therein.

Comment: @phresnel: Indeed, which is why I stated it in the second paragraph.

Comment: @AlecTeal: It's not a tautology - its purpose is to allow multiple definitions (and hence allow inlining in multiple translation units). Without it, as you say, you're not allowed multiple definitions.

Comment: Concerning brace initialization, the explicit constructor should make copy initialization, `T t = {};`, illegal, but `T t{};` should be OK. Although GCC 4.8.2 seems to allow the former. I think that is a bug.

Answer (score -3):

`explicit` with constructors stops them being used implicitly.

`inline` is a way to tell compilers (in ye-olden-days when we lacked [RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory)) that the function is something it'd want to inline. Of course, nowadays they ignore us, or at most humour us with "I'll take it under advisement" with the subtext of "Silly human, thinks I didn't know that already?" (in short, `inline` is ignored these days, the compiler is in a much better position than us to decide to inline).