# Why does clang fail to restrict the construction of a tuple to be explicit?

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17, standard-library, explicit

Per [[tuple.cnstr]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/tuple.cnstr#6):

> ```
> EXPLICIT constexpr tuple();
> ```
>
> Effects: Value-initializes each element.
>
> Remarks: This constructor shall not participate in overload resolution
>   unless `is_­default_­constructible_­v<Ti>` is true for all i.
>   [ *Note:* This behavior can be implemented by a constructor template
>   with default template arguments. — *end note* ] **The
>   constructor is explicit if and only if
>   `Ti` is not implicitly
>   default-constructible for at least one *i*.** [ *Note:* This behavior
>   can be implemented with a trait that checks whether a `const
>   Ti&` can be initialized with `{}`.
>   — *end note* ]

Therefore, the following code

```
#include <tuple>

struct A {
  explicit A() = default;
};

int main()
{
  [[maybe_unused]] std::tuple<A> x = {};
}
```

is ill-formed because the default constructor of `std::tuple<A>` is explicit. [GCC 9.1.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bvgN709XyhMWIeat) correctly raises an error. However, it compiles fine on [Clang 8.0.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zlQ82tlGcunrRqBt).

Here's the relevant code from [libc++](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/tuple#L494-L497):

```
template <class ..._Args>
static constexpr bool __enable_default() {
    return __all<is_default_constructible<_Args>::value...>::value;
}
```

And the [constructor](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/tuple#L608-L613):

```
template <bool _Dummy = true, class = typename enable_if<
    _CheckArgsConstructor<_Dummy>::template __enable_default<_Tp...>()
>::type>
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
_LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR tuple()
    _NOEXCEPT_(__all<is_nothrow_default_constructible<_Tp>::value...>::value) {}
```

It seems that libc++ didn't even think of implementing this.
Is my understanding correct that this is a bug?

Comment: This question is unrelated to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56404292).

Comment: Aren't you *explicitly* calling the constructor with the empty braces initializer `{}`? Why should the `explicit` keyword prevent that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836939/purpose-of-explicit-default-constructors

Comment: There’s nothing more explicit than `std::tuple<A> x{};`.

Comment: @PeteBecker I have updated to use `std::tuple<A> x = {};`. Sorry!

Comment: You could fill a bug report.