# Why does defining an empty copy ctor beside a deleted default ctor make a value initialization with empty list fail?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, default-constructor, value-initialization

In short, why the code below behaves like described in the comments?

```cpp
struct A
{
    A() = delete;
    //A(const A&) {} // uncommenting this...
};

int main()
{
    A a{}; // ... breaks this
    //A(); // this fails in either case because of `A() = delete;` only
}
```

What part of the standard (or at least a page on cppreference) should I look at to understand this?

However, writing `A(const A&) = default;` instead of `//A(const A&) {}` *doesn't* break `A a{};`. What about this? I *think* the underlying cause is the same, but a word from who really knows C++ is better than what I *think*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without the [user-provided](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.fct.def.default#4) copy constructor, `A` is an aggregate. Yes, even though we deleted the default constructor. It's something that was [addressed in C++20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57271400/).

So, prior to C++20, `A a{};` is [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), and so doesn't use the deleted constructor. When you uncomment the copy constructor, `A` stops being an aggregate, thus turning the aggregate initialization into [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). So the initialization of `a` will attempt to call the deleted constructor.

To divine the meaning of an initializer from the standard, one typically starts at [[dcl.init]/16](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init#16). Going through the bullets, one can find how the properties of the initializer (when matched with the properties of the types in question) will affect the way initialization occurs.

Comment: I think this alone is enough the justify C++'s reputation of being only expert-friendly.

Comment: I think this comment of yours can be loudly put as the headline of your answer (and I challenge you to do so! Ahahah :P).

Comment: I suppose a word needed to say whether `without user-defined copy constructor` includes deleted copy constructor or not. Directly deleted one is considered as existing user-defined constructor (it exist! but deleted)

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, I've made a little add up to my question. Would you spend a word on that too?

Comment: @Enlico we just both thought about that at same time? `A(const A&) = default;` makes constructor equivalent to one of aggregate

Comment: @Enlico - I can't say I entirely appreciate moving the goal posts like that. But either way, it's the exact same thing. It's no longer a user-provided copy constructor, so it doesn't interfere with the aggregate status of `A`.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie, actually no. I mis-read your comment first (I read _without user-defined constructor_), which I didn't understand, and thought "what happens if I default construct the copy ctor?".

Comment: I believe I didn't _move_ anything, but I _added_ something which I can't see how far from what originally was in the question is. So ok, @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, sorry for adding that bit, but still...

Comment: @Enlico that's two sides of same coin which have  tail on both ends. Both `A() = delete;
    A(const A&) = delete; ` and `A() = delete;
    A(const A&) = default; ` would compile in C++17, and won't in C++20.

Comment: @Enlico [The fickle aggregate](https://dfrib.github.io/the-fickle-aggregate/) article covers this topic in detail. The TLDR is that C++20 finally sorted out a lot of the confusion with aggregates, with the stronger requirement that an aggregate class may not have _any user-declared_ constructors; meaning even explicitly-defaulted and explicitly-deleted constructors disqualify a class (as of C++20) from being an aggregate.

Comment: @dfrib which really had put sticks into wheels of upgrading code from GNU C++98 \C++11 and of some frameworks\libraries

Answer (score 4):

#### Aggregate initialization is not value initialization

If a given class, say `S`, is an aggregate, then

```
S s{};
```

is aggregate initialization, not value initialization, and will bypass any constructors of `S`, even if they are deleted or private. The *result* of aggregate initialization is typically value-initialization of the (public<sup>(1)</sup>) data members of the aggregate.

<sub>(1) As shown below, a class with any private data member is never an aggregate class, not through any of the C++11 through C++20 standards.</sub>

---

The definition of what is an aggregate class is governed by:

- [[dcl.init.aggr]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init.aggr#1) in C++11 ([N3337](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/))
- [[dcl.init.aggr]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.init.aggr#1) in C++14 ([N4140](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/))
- [[dcl.init.aggr]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.aggr#1) in C++17 ([N4659](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/))
- [[dcl.init.aggr]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init.aggr#1) in C++20 ([N4861](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/))

where the typical confusion with aggregates is the weaker requirement of C++11 through C++17 to not have any *user-provided*<sup>(2)</sup> constructors, which was made much stricter in C++20 with the requirement to not have any *user-declared* constructors.

<sub>(2) The definition of what counts as user-provided function is governed by [[dcl.fct.def.default]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.fct.def.default#4) in C++11 and [[dcl.fct.def.default]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.fct.def.default#5) in C++14 through C++20; the definition of *user-provided* is essentially the same in all these language versions.</sub>

There are also other changes to the definition of aggregates between C++11, C++14 and C++17 that are not as well-known, but that likewise add to the aggregate confusion prior to C++20; we'll walk through a couple of examples to highlight them.

---

#### Is the example an aggregate?

For each example below; if the class `S` of the example is an aggregate (for a particular language version), the following is well-formed:

```
S s{};
```

The aggregate rules in all the examples above likewise applies for any kind of constructor (given that they are otherwise applicable, e.g. allows to be explicitly defaulted or deleted), not just `S()`.

---

```
struct S {};
```

- C++11: yes
- C++14: yes
- C++17: yes
- C++20: yes

---

```
struct S {
    int x;
};
```

- C++11: yes
- C++14: yes
- C++17: yes
- C++20: yes

---

```
struct S {
    int x{42};
};
```

- C++11: no (has a default member initializer)
- C++14: yes
- C++17: yes
- C++20: yes

---

```
class S {
    int x;
};
```

- C++11: no
- C++14: no
- C++17: no
- C++20: no

Has a private data member.

---

```
struct S {
    S() = default;
};
```

- C++11: yes
- C++14: yes
- C++17: yes
- C++20: no (has a user-declared constructor)

---

```
struct S {
 private:
    S() = default;
};
```

- C++11: yes
- C++14: yes
- C++17: yes
- C++20: no (has a user-declared constructor)

---

```
struct S {
    S() = delete;
};
```

- C++11: yes
- C++14: yes
- C++17: yes
- C++20: no (has a user-declared constructor)

---

```
struct S {
    S();
};
S::S() = default;
```

- C++11: no (has a user-provided constructor)
- C++14: no (...)
- C++17: no (...)
- C++20: no (has a user-declared constructor)

An out of line explicitly-defaulted definition counts as user-provided; recalling [dcl.fct.def.default]/4 (C++11) / [dcl.fct.def.default]/5 (C++14, C++17):

> A function is user-provided if it is user-declared and not explicitly defaulted or deleted **on its first declaration**.

---

```
struct S {
    explicit S() = default;
};
```

- C++11: yes
- C++14: yes
- C++17: no (has an `explicit` constructor)
- C++20: no (has a user-declared constructor)

C++17 adds the requirement that an aggregate may not have an `explicit` constructor.

---

```
struct S {
    int x{42};
    S() = delete;
};
```

- C++11: no (has a default member initializer)
- C++14: yes
- C++17: yes
- C++20: no (has a user-declared constructor)

C++14 removed the requirement of C++11 for an aggregate to have no default member initializers.

---

```
struct S {
    int x{42};
    explicit S() = delete;
};
```

- C++11: no (has a default member initializer)
- C++14: yes
- C++17: no (has an `explicit` constructor)
- C++20: no (has a user-declared constructor)