# Is a float member guaranteed to be zero initialized with {} syntax?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

In C++17, consider a case where `S` is a struct with a deleted default constructor and a float member, when S is initialized with empty braces, is the float member guaranteed by the standard to be zero-initialized?

```cpp
struct A {
  int x{};
};

struct S
{
  S() = delete;
 
  A a;
  float b;
};

int main()
{
  auto s = S{}; // Is s.b guaranteed to be zero?
}
```

In my opinion, cppreference.com is not clear, saying both that:

> If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of members and basesor initializer list is completely empty, the remaining members and bases (since C++17) are initialized by their default member initializers, if provided in the class definition, and otherwise (since C++14) copy-initialized from empty lists, in accordance with the usual list-initialization rules (which performs value-initialization for non-class types and non-aggregate classes with default constructors, and aggregate initialization for aggregates). If a member of a reference type is one of these remaining members, the program is ill-formed.

([from here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)), which implies that b is guaranteed to be zero

> In all cases, if the empty pair of braces {} is used and T is an aggregate type, aggregate-initialization is performed instead of value-initialization.

([from here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization))

which implies that b is not guaranteed to be zero.

There is also a discussion that seems to imply that while not guaranteed, all known compiler zero-initialize anyway:

> The standard specifies that zero-initialization is not performed when the class has a user-provided or deleted default constructor, even if that default constructor is not selected by overload resolution. All known compilers performs additional zero-initialization if a non-deleted defaulted default constructor is selected.

Related to [Why does aggregate initialization not work anymore since C++20 if a constructor is explicitly defaulted or deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57271400/why-does-aggregate-initialization-not-work-anymore-since-c20-if-a-constructor)

Comment: I don't know... Is the delete not supposed to prevent default construction? Or is it still the case that a stupid C++ rule allows side-stepping the deletion?

Comment: The provided example compiles. It does not call the default construtor but does aggregate initialization

Comment: C++20 fixes that stupid rule

Comment: BTW: your code does not compile with the c++20 standard.

Comment: That's great news! My question is explicitly for C++17 though.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Do you have a link about the C++20 fix?

Comment: This is the paper that was voted into C++20 https://wg21.link/P1008R1

Comment: The second quote comes from the value-initialization page, which says that your structure will be aggregate-initialized. So that means the first quote is the one that details how the structure will be initialized. And that quote says that the members will be [list-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). And since no list is provided, the members will be individually value-initialized (or aggregate-initialized, depending on type). So `b` will be value-initialized and zero.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica thanks for the link. I've discovered the `explicit` trick and answered myself thanks to you. Technically I'm still looking for the answer about whether b will be zero initialized or not, but practically the explicit trick solves my real problem!

Comment: Happy to help. I feel I should point out that this obscure quirk did have one upside. It allowed you to write aggregates that did not permit indeterminate values. Consider  https://wandbox.org/permlink/aq1t3bMV9ORogvMy - And notice how only the default (and problematic) initialization is disabled. I still agree that the rule was too arcane and weird to stay, but it wasn't all bad.

Comment: Oh I see. That's actually pretty nice. In C++20 you'd need to manually provide the trivial constructor that forwards the arguments from the initializer list to mimick aggretate initialization. I see.

Comment: @fouronnes [The fickle aggregate](https://dfrib.github.io/the-fickle-aggregate/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `S` is an aggregate, `S{}` will perform aggregate initialization. The rule in the standard about how members are initialized when there are no initializers in the list is [basically what you cited](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.aggr#8):

> - If the element has a default member initializer ([class.mem]), the element is initialized from that initializer.
> - Otherwise, if the element is not a reference, the element is copy-initialized from an empty initializer list ([dcl.init.list]).

So for b, that's the equivalent of `float b = {};`. Per the rules of list initialization, we have to get [all the way down to 3.10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.list#3.10):

> Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements, the object is value-initialized.

And value initialization will initialize a `float` to 0.

Answer (score 6):

This is a quirk of C++ that is [fixed in C++20](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1008r1.pdf). In the meantime you can add `explicit` to the deleted default constructor to force the struct to become non-aggregate, and make your code a guaranteed compile error:

```cpp
struct A {
  int x{};
};

struct S
{
  explicit S() = delete;
 
  const A a;
  const float b;
};

int main()
{
  auto s = S{}; // error: call to deleted constructor of 'S'
}
```